# Como formatar o textfield com negrito no Ireport?

Tags: relatório, ireport, jasper-reports

Usei a barra de ferramentas e apliquei o negrito para os campos, que visualmente alteraram, como pode ser percebido na imagem, mas no pdf gerado a formatação não é exibida. Estou usando a versão 4.0.1 do Ireport.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As propriedades atribuídas aos elementos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: lembrou-se de compilar novamente o seu relatorio antes de testar ?

Comment: Sim, @CristianUrbainski. O relatório foi compilado diversas vezes.

Comment: @woliveirajr, vou atualizar o post para colocar as propriedades dos textfield.

Answer (score 1):

Obrigado por postar a imagem das propriedades do campo, eu estava pensando se não poderia ter sido alguma fonte especial que não estivesse sendo processada corretamente.

Nas propriedades a fonte SansSerif já está selecionada, então não consigo ver se ela estava "acima da linha" ou "abaixo da linha" quando você clica na seta para selecionar outra fonte. Se ela estava abaixo da linha, isto significa que ela não estaria disponível para você (estaria presente no seu sistema mas não disponível para o iReport).

De uma olhada nisto (e no site http://mdahlman.wordpress.com/2010/05/28/jaspersoft-v3-7-font-extensions/ ) e veja se não é o seu caso.

Answer (score 0):

Olha você pode tentar mudar o campo "Pdf Font name is now" de "Helvetica" 
para "Helvetica-Bold" .

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, você deve selecionar a fonte correspondente para o PDF pelo atributo "PDF Font..." que apesar de ser apresentada como depreciada continua funcionando e eu também costumo marcar a opção "Pdf Embedded".

Estou utilizando a versão 6.1.1 e continua a mesma coisa.